# Is it possible to automate for generating MCDC Truth table out of logical expression as a input using any scripting language

Tags: automation, logical-operators, mc-dc

Suppose if I give any logical expression to tool as a input along with each signal definition, Tool should be able to generate `MCDC` truth table (used in `Avionics V&V`).  If it is possible, can we implement timing and robustness too?

Ex:

##Input to tool

Inputs:

```
  Logical Expression: OUT = (C1 ||(C2 && C3 && (C4 || C5 || C6)))
```

#### Expected output of Tool

```
 Truth Table:

  TC   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6  INIT  **OUT**   
   1   T  F  T  T  F  F     F    **T**        
   1   F  F  T  T  F  F     T    **T**                                                          
   2   F  T  T  T  F  F     F    **T**                                                        
   2   F  T  F  T  F  F     T    **F**                                                          
   3   F  T  T  F  T  F     F    **T**                                                         
   3   F  T  T  F  F  F     T    **F**                                                          
   4   F  F  T  T  F  F     F    **F**                                                        
   5   F  T  T  F  F  T     F    **T**
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. But anything you tried so far?

Comment: @ Sri Harsha kappala I'm thinking to implement this using python or vb script but not getting how and where to start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a truth table for your expression (in this case it would be 2^6 cases).
2. Pick from the truth table the case that fits MCDC. Let's take your expression for example. For C1: pick cases that only C1 and OUT change state (from TRUE to FALSE); other conditions do not change state.

Take a look at these tools
written in [C#](https://www.digitalobjectivo.com/mcdc-test-cases-generator/) and [C++](http://aerotools.blogspot.com/2011/04/modified-condition-decision-coverage.html).

Comment: The C# tool link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a tool that does create a truthtable and create test vectors. I did exactly that in C++. You can find it here:

[MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)

The boolean expression will be parsed, compiled for a virtual machine and evaluated. That gives a truth table. Quine & McCluskey is used to produce an irredundant normal form.

And, the tool shows all MCDC test pairs, including Msking and "Unique cause+Masking"